# AJAX called PHP can't read URL

Tags: php, ajax, url

Consider a two language site where the english version of a page is called via `?lang=en` The following AJAX call seems to work fine for printing sidebar of RSS news:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup ({  
                cache: false  
            });
            $('.msg_head').eq(0).click(function(){
                $('.msg_body').eq(0).load('printSideNews.php');
                $('.loadMessage').eq(2).hide();
            });
```

printSideNews.php starts as follows:

```
function checkNewsLanguage(){
        $requiredURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $Languag = explode('?lang=',$requiredURL);
        $myLanguage = $Languag[1];
        //echo $myLanguage;
        if($myLanguage == 'en')
            return false;
        else return true;
    }
```

For some reason the language check which is checking the URL doesn't work. I can't get the english version of the news sidebar. If I directly go to `news.php(no AJAX used but same PHP functions)` where I use absolutely the same procedure the language switch is working. Any help solving this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: any reason you can't just check `$_GET['lang']` instead of that _SERVER/explode/array business?

Comment: @Marc haha, beat me. @George Is there any particular reason you need to check `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` instead of `$_GET["lang"]`?

Comment: You're right but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: When is the `lang` set ?

Comment: @ Interstellar_Coder; After clciking a flag image which is a link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AJAX call never passes the lang parameter, try adding `data: { lang: 'en' }` to your ajaxSetup call.

**UPDATE**
Correction:

```
$('.msg_body').eq(0).load('printSideNews.php', 'lang=en');
```

Comment: In that case, try calling like this `$('.msg_body').eq(0).load('printSideNews.php', {lang: 'en'});` if it works, I'll change the answer to match.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work; the idea is that if I have news.php load bg news if it's news.php?lang=en load english which works with pure PHP and without AJAX

Comment: Sorry, I read just read the documentation and it says passing data as an object as an argument turns it into a `POST`, use `$('.msg_body').eq(0).load('printSideNews.php', 'lang=en');` instead.

Comment: No problem, just glad I could help.